# How do I build 2 jar files with different dependencies?

Tags: java, ant, build, dependencies, ivy

I have two different versions of the same third-party library, and need to deploy to two different systems.  Each system uses a different version of the library.

**LibraryA** and **LibraryB** have the same API interface and my code is currently built with **LibraryA** and deployed to **SystemA**.  Now I need a second version that is built with **LibraryB** and deployed to **SystemB**.

Of course I could copy/paste my code and compile each project with a different library, but this seems like a maintenance nightmare.  Both libraries can be installed and developed against concurrently.  Currently I am using Ant, but everything is on the table and anything that could help would be considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working with an enhanced Ant build files and Eclipse settings.  This fulfilled our requirements of a temporary ability to toggle Libraries in Eclipse, Compile/Test using both Libraries and deploy to different environments.

The Ant build script originally compiled and tested over LibraryA and I copied and pasted another section for LIbraryB.  This allows the project to compile with both LibraryA and LibraryB and runs JUnint tests over both libraries.

The startup script was modified to 
  java -cp "Project.jar:$SYMLINK_LIB/*" project.main [space delimited arguments]

$SYMLINK_LIB contains symlinks to the jar libraries differing between two different environments.

Eclipse Configuration

1. Built a project for LibraryA and LibraryB
2. For both projects, right click on the project
   a. Click on "Libraries" and "Add JARs"
      i. Add the jar files necessary for this Library
   b. Click on tab "Order and Export"
      ii. Check all jar files so that they will be used by any Project that imports this project.
   c. Click "OK"
3. Right click on the project that needs to import LibraryA and LibraryB
   a. Click on tab "Projects" and "Add" to add Project LibraryA (or LibraryB)
   b. If this project is going to be imported by other projects that will require access to LibraryA or LibraryB - click on "Order and Export" and select LibraryA and LibraryB.
   c. Click "OK"

Answer (score 0):

You need a dependency manager. [Apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) would be my tool of choice.

## Example

After running my build:

```
├── build
│   ├── ivy
│   │   ├── com.myspotontheweb-demo-compile.html
│   │   ├── com.myspotontheweb-demo-runtimeA.html
│   │   ├── com.myspotontheweb-demo-runtimeB.html
│   │   └── ivy-report.css
│   ├── systemA
│   │   ├── log4j-1.2.17.jar
│   │   ├── slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
│   │   └── slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar     <-- Version 1.7.5
│   └── systemB
│       ├── log4j-1.2.17.jar
│       ├── slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
│       └── slf4j-log4j12-1.7.4.jar     <-- Version 1.7.4
├── build.xml
└── ivy.xml
```

Note:

- The **systemA** and **systemB** directories contain two different versions of the same jar.
- I have configured my build to generate dependency management reports. Useful for troubleshooting and documentation.

### ivy.xml

Ivy uses a concept called configurations for managing different groups of dependences. In this case we create a configuration for 3rd party jars required for compilation and then two more to handle the SystemA and SystemB dependencies:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>

    <configurations>
        <conf name="compile"  description="Required to compile application"/>
        <conf name="runtimeA" description="System A runtime dependencies" extends="compile"/>
        <conf name="runtimeB" description="System A runtime dependencies" extends="compile"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- compile dependencies -->
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.7.5" conf="compile->default"/>

        <!-- runtimeA dependencies -->
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.7.5" conf="runtimeA->default"/>

        <!-- runtimeB dependencies -->
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.7.4" conf="runtimeB->default"/>

    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

   <property name="build.dir" location="build"/>

   <target name="bootstrap" description="Install ivy">
      <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
      <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ivy.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar"/>
   </target>

   <target name="resolve" description="Use ivy to resolve classpaths">
      <ivy:resolve/>
      <ivy:report todir='${build.dir}/ivy' graph='false' xml='false'/>
      <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path" conf="compile"/>
   </target>

   <target name="build" depends="resolve" description="Do something with each set of runtime jars">
      <ivy:retrieve pattern="${build.dir}/systemA/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" conf="runtimeA"/>
      <ivy:retrieve pattern="${build.dir}/systemB/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" conf="runtimeB"/>
   </target>

   <target name="clean" description="Cleanup build files">
      <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
   </target>

   <target name="clean-all" depends="clean" description="Additionally purge ivy cache">
      <ivy:cleancache/>
   </target>

</project>
```

Notes:

- The [retrieve](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/retrieve.html) task is used to populate a chosen directory with file collections managed by ivy.
- The **bootstrap** target will download and install the ivy task jar
- The [cachepath](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cachepath.html) and [report](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/report.html) tasks are useful additional tasks
- Ivy caches downloaded files, so it's always a good idea to include a [cleancache](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cleancache.html) task (all caches get dirty)